# Multiple context managers in a "with" statement in python

Tags: python, contextmanager

I'm curious why the following code:

```
l1= threading.Lock()
l2= threading.Lock()
l3=threading.Lock()
with l1 and l2 and l3:
  print l1.locked()
  print l2.locked()
  print l3.locked()
```

prints this:

```
False
False
True
```

I realize that the right syntax is:

```
with l1, l2, l3:
```

but I'm trying to find an explanation for why only l3 was locked.

Comment: The expression `l1 and l2 and l3` here would evaluate to `l3`. Your context manager is only managing lock `l3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this, consider how `and` works in Python.

The result of the expression `x and y` is equivalent to `y if x else x`, except that it only evaluates `x` once. That is, when `bool(x)` is `True`, the `and` operator results in `y`, otherwise it results in `x` (and doesn't evaluate `y`).

Unless an object defines its own `__bool__` dunder method, `bool(obj)` will generally be `True`. This is the case for lock objects. So `bool(l1)` is `True`, and the expression `l1 and l2 and l3` evaluates as `l2 and l3`. Then since `bool(l2)` is `True`, this expression evaluates as `l3`.

So the `with` statement ends up managing the lock `l3`, and therefore that's the one which is locked in the body of the `with` statement. As you note, if you want to manage multiple locks at once, you should pass them separated by commas.